# Dynamic card generation on button click

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to dynamically generate card and contents inside card. I can dynamically generate contents but I don't know how to dynamically generate a separate card for each time I generate the content. Actually the dynamically generated contents are coming inside one same card but I want in separate card

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
<div *ngFor="let cities of city; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
  City:    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="city[in].value" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
<div *ngFor="let states of state; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
  State:    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state[in].value" name="names{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
    <div *ngFor="let zips of zip; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
      Zipcode:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="zip[in].value" name="namess{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="text-center btn-danger"  (click)="add()">Add input</button>
<br/>
<br/>


<br />
<br />
{{words2 | json}}
```

**TS**

```
  name: String;
  country: String;
  profiles = [];
  city = [{value: ''}];
  state = [{value: ''}];
  zip = [{value: ''}];
  constructor() { }


  add() {
    this.city.push({value: ''});
    this.state.push({value: ''});
    this.zip.push({value: ''});
  }
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdyygt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please do not refer to external sites. Make a [mcve] and post the problematic code part in your question as the external page may disappear and the question wouldn't be helpful any longer.

Comment: I belive he did.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngFor` for cards instead of every input individually.

Use normal data model - so array of model objects not arrays of individual model properties

Working code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6aeeuk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Also you have missuses Bootstrap form classes so it is totally messy now. Please reffer to Bootstrap's documentation and examples onto how to create forms with labels.